# RSA for Google Apps Scripts: How to use the Utilities class?

Tags: google-apps-script, rsa, private-key

I tried to use the Utilities class, but I am in doubt, since it apparently is not able to generate the keys I need for RSA encryption.

```
    // This writes an array of bytes to the log.
var signature = Utilities.computeRsaSignature(Utilities.RsaAlgorithm.RSA_SHA_256,
    "this is my input",
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivatekeyhere\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
Logger.log(signature);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities

My application consists of a bot for Hangouts Chat in which users perform a voting action that is encrypted and recorded in a spreadsheet. Subsequently, at the end of the vote, the user who created the election decrypts the votes using the bot and posts the final result of the election.

For security reasons, the ideal would be for the encryption key to be a different key from the decryption key, something that can be achieved with RSA. In addition, these keys must be changed periodically through the bot itself that would generate random passwords. Thus, it would not be possible to determine the key for any user, neither the voters nor the electoral commission.

Comment: google appscript support RSA encryting function by using Utilities. Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(value, key);

Comment: I need to use RSA to encrypt text with one key and decrypt it with another key at another time. I'm not sure how the Utilities class can help me in this case.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Pls try with this.
Signs the provided value using the specified RSA algorithm with the given key and charset.

```
// This writes an array of bytes to the log.
var signature = Utilities.computeRsaSignature(Utilities.RsaAlgorithm.RSA_SHA_256,
    "this is my input",
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivatekeyhere\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    Utilities.Charset.US_ASCII);
Logger.log(signature);
```

Comment: But how do I generate the private and public keys?

Comment: I need to use RSA to encrypt text with one key and decrypt it with another key at another time. I'm not sure how the Utilities class can help me in this case.

Comment: Hello.  You can move this github code to appscript to generate key pairs based on password. please refer this url(https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico)

Comment: If you want to help in making RSA Key pair. I will do it for you at low cost

Comment: I tried to use Cryptico, but I was not very happy with the adaptation. I need to generate different keys regularly to ensure better security for my application.